# Assertion failed- map/set iterators are incompatibile

Tags: c++, dictionary

There seems to be a weird bug in my code thats crashing when i make a call
`dijkstra(cont)`. "cont" is a map declared as `map<string, poz> cont;` where poz is my own class, and the function is `void dijkstra(map<string, poz> cont)`. I tried passing the container as a reference and so on but it hadnt made any effect.

Comment: What question are you trying to ask?

Comment: Guess i hadnt made it clear. Im asking if theres some sort of mistake in what i posted, because my program keeps crashing at the dijkstra function call.

Comment: You haven't posted enough of anything to tell whether there is a mistake. Can you show a minimal compilable example (just take out _everything_ that isn't required to reproduce the problem)?

Comment: Please post some code. You got the description, that is good, but you should also post relevant part of the code to reduce the guesswork based on your description.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the container by value, which means you'll be making a copy as it gets passed. The iterators must point to the same container they were generated from or you'll get the "incompatible" error.

Try passing by reference instead:

```
void dijkstra(map<string, poz> & cont)
```

Comment: Although it isnt a direct solution, your answer helped me to find out what is really going wrong in my code, thanks!